# How can I apply locale to decimal formatting in Excel?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, localization

I am generating excel from code.I am trying to customize the cells through .net code.
and I also want to add the localization , so that after generating the excel when the user tries to enter the decimal it should take that locale number format.

how to format decimals with thousand seperator en-US a number looks like 1,000.45 and Dutch-Belgium it becomes 1.000,45 I mentioned decimal in my code as worksheet.Range(Range).NumberFormat = "###,###.##"

How to chnage this format for different locales.

Kinldy help me.

Thank you
Ramesh.T.

Comment: That should adopt the regional settings that the user has set.  Did you test it?  What happened?

Comment: No James, I didnt test it, Is that by defualt it takes the regional format by defualt without mentioning externally

Comment: If you have it in this format, whatever locale is set on the machine is used.  It will localize the date if it is in that format.

Comment: how to format decimals with thousand seperator en-US a number looks like 1,000.45 and Dutch-Belgium it becomes 1.000,45                I mentioned decimal in my code  as                          worksheet.Range(Range).NumberFormat = "###,###.##"

Comment: That does not sound like fun, I don't envy you, whenever I have tried to do more advanced or more 'generic' things in Excel it has been a nasty hack or just not brilliant code or I gave up =)

Answer (score 2):

I access Excel through COM from my business application and use:

```
rg.NumberFormat = "#" + e.ThousandsSeparator + "##0" + e.DecimalSeparator + "00"
```

where `e` is of type Excel.Application and `rg` is a Range.

Strangely in plain excel VBA I have to write directly "#,##0.00", because using the same construct as above results in a bogus format.

The idea is taken from another stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972487/excel-print-number-with-correct-decimal-seperator). You can find all the separators searching in Excel's object browser for *separator*.

Answer (score 1):

The options button (in excel2007 under office button, below right) advanced function lets you select the decimal point or comma independent from regional setting (uncheck use system separator)